# How do i join multiple cells into one

Tags: sql

[Problem Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXzFo.png)

Hi, im trying to put in the same cell those 3 results of "ProductName" so i ll get as result only 1 row per company
and the 1rst one will look up like this

1 // Alfreds Futterkiste // 4342.53 // Escargots de Bourgogne, Chartreuse verte, Vegie-spread

Thank you so much

Comment: What is your SQL "flavor"? MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, ...?

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(\`CompanyName\`, "//", \`Total Comparado\`, "//", \`ProductName\`) FROM your_table_name`. -- `CONCAT` works with most flavors of SQL.

Comment: @Zak - OP needs some form of aggregated CONCAT, something like `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL.

Comment: @Alberto Adrianzén You should specify the variant of sql in order to get an answer suitable to your case, as @PM 77-1 states. Also @PM 77-1 is right, you need `group_concant` and `group by CompanyName` after your `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by based on all fields, other than **ProductName** 
and aggregate ProductName to a string/array/etc.

In a PostgreSQL sql syntax it would be:

```
select Id, CompanyName, TotalComprado, string_agg(ProductName, ',')
group by Id, CompanyName, TotalComprado
```